# How can I filter data through a join table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

There are tables: groups, targets and join table groups_targets.

Groups have targets, for example:

- Group #1 has a **gender** target, an **age** target, and a **city** target
- Group #2 has a **gender** target
- Group #3 has a **city** and **gender** target.
- Group #4 has an **age** and **city** target.

My request does not return anything

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.* 
FROM groups 
INNER JOIN groups_targets ON groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1 
AND (targets.name = 'age' AND targets.name = 'gender')
```

How to find groups that have both **gender** and **age**, only group #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(targets.name = 'age' AND targets.name = 'gender')` will always return false, targets.name can't have two values at the same time, Use `OR` instead of `AND` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.* 
FROM groups 
INNER JOIN groups_targets ON groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1 
AND (targets.name = 'age' OR targets.name = 'gender');
```

If both targets should be there, we can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses alongside the `CASE` clause to specifically choose groups containing both targets :

```
SELECT groups.id
FROM groups 
INNER JOIN groups_targets ON groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1 
GROUP BY groups.id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN targets.name = 'age' THEN 1 END) >= 1
       AND COUNT(CASE WHEN targets.name = 'gender' THEN 1 END) >= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

To get all groups having target `age` use the join query with the proper filter on `target name`

```
SELECT   groups.id 
FROM groups 
INNER JOIN groups_targets ON groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id and targets.name = 'age' 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1;

id|
--+
 1|
 4|
```

Use similar query for the target `gender`

```
SELECT   groups.id 
FROM groups 
INNER JOIN groups_targets ON groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id and targets.name = 'gender' 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1;

id|
--+
 1|
 2|
 3|
```

To get groups with both targets use `intersect` of the previous queries, i.e. `group_id`'s returned in both queries

```
SELECT   groups.id 
FROM groups 
INNER JOIN groups_targets ON groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id and targets.name = 'age' 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1 
intersect
SELECT   groups.id 
FROM groups 
INNER JOIN groups_targets ON groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id and targets.name = 'gender' 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1; 

id|
--+
 1|
```

Answer (score 0):

To find groups that have both gender and age targets, you should use a different approach, such as using the EXISTS clause with subqueries.

```
SELECT DISTINCT groups.* 
FROM groups 
WHERE groups.user_id = 1 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM groups_targets 
    INNER JOIN targets ON targets.id = groups_targets.target_id 
    WHERE groups_targets.group_id = groups.id 
    AND targets.name IN ('age', 'gender')
    GROUP BY groups_targets.group_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT targets.name) = 2
);
```

The query should give you the desired result, which is finding groups that have both gender and age targets.

Hope this helps.